# How the line number 4 of below code is taking the input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
  angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
    .filter('reverse', function() { 
           return function(input, uppercase) {
             input = input || ''; //  declaring the variable
                var out = '';
               for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
              out = input.charAt(i) + out;
            }
          // if condition for uppercase
            if (uppercase) {
              out = out.toUpperCase();
            }
            return out;//return statement
          };
        });
```

The code defines a filter for AngularJS that takes a string as input and returns the string in reverse order as well as uppercase.

I couldn't understand the code that is written in line number 4 that takes the input:

```
input = input || ''; //  declaring the variable
```

It will be helpful if any one can describe me how line number 4 is taking input.

Comment: I'd be cautious using `||` to set default values, it is often better to use a guard statement as in my answer below, here is a link to an article on why http://www.codereadability.com/javascript-default-parameters-with-or-operator/

Answer (score 3):

`input = input || '';` can be substituted with the following guard statement which should be easier to read:

```
if (!input) {
  input = '';
}
```

What `input = input || ''` really means is that if `input` is [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), default `input` to an empty string.

Arguments in Javascript are optional, if you were to call the filter without passing an argument, `input` would be set to `undefined`. Guarding in this way lets you save vertical space, but it's worth noting that guards like this are only effective if arguments cannot be `falsey`.

Comment: your 3 lines do different thing(

Comment: unfortunately, nope-) you forgot about null

Comment: yes, i didn't add `|| input === false` but it's meant to explain a concept not be directly substituted

Comment: The above explanation is really helpful. Thanks a lot